# M1 Mac unable to switch bash

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, apple-silicon

Greeting!

I followed the answers [in here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193411/update-bash-to-version-4-0-on-osx) and got the latest version (5.2.15) of `bash` installed on my Mac. But when I ran `bash --version` it still shows:

```
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (arm64-apple-darwin22)
```

I check the `/etc/shells` and the newly installed `bash` path is in the list:

```
...
/bin/zsh
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/bash/5.2.15/bin/bash
```

When I tried running `dscl . -read ~/ UserShell` it shows the newly installed `bash`.

```
UserShell: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/bash/5.2.15/bin/bash
```

I already restarted the Terminal and my mac but to no avail.

I also tried changing the `Shells open with:` in Terminal settings to `Default login shell` and `Command (complete path)` but both still show the `3.2.57 version`

Also I already found [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/221918/why-i-am-unable-to-switch-bash-to-the-one-installed-by-homebrew) but I don't the tmux installed on my Mac.

Any idea about this? I need to run a `.sh` file and it require `bash` 4 or above

**UPDATE:**

Running `which bash` shows `/bin/bash`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most likely you switched shells successfully, but use the wrong command to check the version. `bash --version` will start a *new* `bash` from `PATH`, in your case this is `/bin/bash`. Use `echo $BASH_VERSION` instead to check the version.

Nevertheless, it's a bad idea to use a path pointing to the Homebrew Cellar, it will break as soon as Bash gets updated to 5.2.16. Most binaries installed via Homebrew are linked to from `$(brew --prefix)/bin` (`/opt/homebrew/bin` for M1/M2), so to fix this

- edit `/etc/shells` (`sudo nano /etc/shells`), replace `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/bash/5.2.15/bin/bash` with `/opt/homebrew/bin/bash`
- run `chsh -s /opt/homebrew/bin/bash`
- open Terminal settings and set "Shells open with" to "Default login shell"

Then restart Terminal.